# OS X API to access iOS photo library?

Tags: macos, ios4

Lightroom running on OS X (don't know about Windows) can directly access the Photo Library of my iPad to import photos.

Is there an OS X API for this?

Or, perhaps Adobe wrote their own low-level code? (No prohibition on doing this for OS X, unlike iOS.)

(Note: I can access the Photo Library just fine from my iOS app. This question is about doing it from an OS X app.)

--Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: The iOS devices use the standard PTP protocol. The ImageCaptureCore framework handles that on OS X, and I think WIA on Windows (haven't tried WIA yet).

--Marc